# Trying to get data from peoplesoft using component interaface in java. Not able to create session

Tags: java, peoplesoft

Is there any other way of testing for connection to PeopleSoft from java.
this is not working for me

**ERROR:**

> bea.jolt.JoltException: NwHdlr: IO
>   exceptions\njava.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>     at bea.jolt.NwHdlr.open_socket(NwHdlr.java:2240)

```java
import psft.pt8.joa.API;
import psft.pt8.joa.ISession;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(test());

    }

    public static boolean test()
    {
        boolean status;
        try {


            ISession session = API.createSession();

            boolean isSuccess = session.connectS(1, "//129.154.79.140:9033", "PS", "PS", new byte[0], "PS");

            if(isSuccess)
            {
                status = true;
            }
            else    
            {
                status = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            //To create localized exception ExceptionManager.createNlsAdapterSDKException(ExceptionManager.createNlsAdapterSDKException(MessageBundle.getInstance(),Messages.Test_CONN_SUCC_200, arguments);

            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Elad Altstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15379451) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67050677) saying "Are you sure port 9033 you’re trying to access is the port that’s defined for Jolt Listener (JSL) in your psappsrv.cfg file?"